# Remote server doesn't accept password, ruby script 'net/ssh'

Tags: ruby, networking, connection, net-ssh

I connect using ruby to the remote, pass the command, but   channel.send_data ("passwd\n") dont work , I cant catch in than the reason. The password doesn't pass.

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'net/ssh'
...

Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password) do |session|
stdout = ""
session.exec!(@cmd) do |channel, stream, data|  
    if data =~ /Password/ 
        channel.send_data("passw\n")
    end
    stdout << data
end   
puts stdout
session.close 
end
```

Comment: From the server side, SSH login with password can be disabled explicitly but only accept login with SSH key. And this is a common setting to secure the server. So I'd suggest you try the login with ssh command first, to make sure if the password login is allowed.

Comment: @hailong if  cmd = "ls" or "cd ..", then succes, but if cmd must password confirmation then failed, exemple  - fatal: could not read Password for '': No such device or address